# Can I create Primary Key Factory with MongoMapper? How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory, mongomapper

Can I create Primary Key Factory with MongoMapper? How?

It's interesting that MongoMapper map treats "id" as an alias of "_id" when MongoDB doesn't? Isn't this oversight?